# I am not able to test Application Variables in my Test Project

Tags: c#, variables, testing, nunit, state

I was trying to do some POC on Test Drven Development. In my project I am using Application State Variables, So I need to fake them as HttpContext is not available during TDD execution.

I have search and found some code to fake the Application variable. The code looks like this:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void StartReportService_ApplicationStateShouldContainMyIndex()
{
    //No HttpApplicationBase in System.Web.Abstractions, must use Real Object
    var application = new Mock<HttpApplication>();

    //Real object does not have a property of type HttpApplicationStateBase so must use real one?
    //var applicationStateBase = new Mock<HttpApplicationStateBase>();

    //real one not creable so HACK get private constructor
    var ctor = typeof(HttpApplicationState).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[] { }, new ParameterModifier[] { });
    var applicationState = (HttpApplicationState)ctor.Invoke(new Object[] { });

    //fails here, HttpApplication.Application not overridable
    application.SetupProperty(x => x.Application, applicationState);


    var plugin = HttpApplicationPlugin.HttpApplicationPluginInstance;
    plugin.Application_Start(application.Object,null);


}
```

I am not able to find the HttpApplicationPlugin class. Could anyone please help?

Comment: What language is this? some microsoft thing?

Comment: Yes. Its C#, using NUnit for Testing